# IPA file recreation with updated Provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using adhoc distribution for my product. So that when there is new device i have update the provisioning profile and download it and rebuild the IPA file using the source. Is there a way to update the previous IPA with new provisioning profile without recreating it.

Comment: Not possible. You have to recreate IPA file with the new provisioning profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time when you are creating new provisioning, you need to create new ipa file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [iResign](http://code.google.com/p/iresign/) it will do what you want.

We use it for enterprise builds but should work just fine for yours.